# Retrieve raw sleep data from Beddit in csv format

Tags: javascript, python, device, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I'm using a Misfit Beddit device. I would like to retrieve the raw sleep data in .csv format then analyse and plot it using macros.

The parameters needed are skin_temperature, heart rate, gsr, toss_turns and sleep_type (for example, deep, REM and light). The interval for the time ought to be 1 minute for every row. I have retrieved data in various ways using Node.js, Python, etc. However, they were not helpful as it was not in the required format.

Here's an example of data from a Basis device:

[image: Sample data]

This is how I would need to retrieve data from Beddit sleep device. I know how to auto plot using macros. Any ideas on how to retrieve data from a Beddit device?

Comment: How did you retrieve data from Beddit with Python/Node.js? Did you use the [Beddit API](https://github.com/beddit/beddit-api#section-beddit-api)?

Comment: Yes, I used the Beddit API. However, I do not know how to alter the codes such that I retrieve the data in the same format as above. (.csv) @approxiblue